# Why is Pytorch Dataset and DataLoader necessary?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I've been searching for answers to this question for a long time and haven't found a good response for it. Why is Dataset and DataLoader used? It seems unnecessary, especially for Dataset because you need to override the `__len__` and `__getitem__` functions yourself when it can already be done prior to creating the Dataset class.

I've read the documentation and "`torch.utils.data.Dataset` is an abstract class representing a dataset" doesn't exactly explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

Formalism like this is generally implemented to enforce consistent interfaces across projects using a given library/framework. This makes sharing code and collaborating in industrial or research settings more streamlined and efficient.

Similar paradigms can be found in Tensorflow, SKLearn, XGBoost, etc.